# Mongodb add condition to filter into aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add a condition in my aggregation to get only elements that contain a specific id (like counters.id=1209 in example below ).

My aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('counters').aggregate([ { "$match" : 
    { "module" : "iecc" , "machine" : "COM01" , "colx" : 42 , "idcpt" : { "$in" 
: [ 1209 , 1210 , 1217 , 1211 , 1212 , 1213 , 1214 , 1207 , 1208 , 1225 , 1215 
, 1216]}}} , 
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$coly" , "counters" : { "$push" : { "id" : "$idcpt" 
, "value" : "$val" , "Tcrea" : "$tcreation"}}}} , 
    { "$sort" : { "counters.1209" : -1 ,"counters.Tcrea" : -1 }}
    ] 
)
```

actual result:

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"counters" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 1207,
        "value" : NumberLong(1),
        "Tcrea" : NumberLong(0)
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 1209,
        "value" : "004130",
        "Tcrea" : NumberLong(1525962174)
    }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : 2,
    "counters" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1207,
            "value" : NumberLong(1),
            "Tcrea" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    ]
}
```

The expected result is to get only the first element id=1.
I'm trying "$project" with "$exists" but it don't work :(

```
{ "$project" : { counters.id : { "$exists" : true, "$in" : 1209}
```

} }

What's going wrong?

All ideas will be welcome !!

Comment: Add $match stage instead of project. like `{ "$match" : {$expr:{$in:[1209, "$counters.id"]}}}`

Comment: thank you for your quickly answer, My Mongodb version is 3.4 so i can't use this command.

Comment: Yw. Try `{$addFields:{flag:{$in:[1209, "$counters.id"]}}}, {$match:{flag:true}}` for 3.4.

Comment: it works :) and for the first cmd i replace $expr by counter.id and it works also, thx